# How to generate and visualize results of all possible parameter values in Python?

Tags: python, statistics

I have two parameters: `demand`, `ticket_qty`.

`demand` is an integer and can have a possible range of [100 - 200]

`ticket_qty` is also an integer and can have a possible range of [0 - 200]

I want to visualize how values for the above parameters affect the functions below:

`price = demand - tickets_qty`

`revenue = price * ticket_qty`

In Excel I created two matrixes (price and revenue) with `demand` as row indexes and `ticket_qty` as column indexes and simply applied the formula for each cell based on the rules above. However, seeing as this is a Kaggle microchallenge, I'd like to perform this using Python so as to then be able to plot and show optimal levels of price/revenue and do all my work inside the Jupyter notebook.

Questions:

- How would I go about doing this in Python? pandas? numpy?
- In statistics/data science, what is this "process" of mapping out possible values called? So as to facilitate further research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably fastest to do this using numpy, in which you can define the possible ranges of your values using `numpy.arange` as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

demand = np.arange(100, 201, 1) # integers from 100-200 inclusive
ticket_qty = np.arange(0, 201, 1) # integers from 0-200 inclusive
```

If you then want to calculate the possibilities using the different values you can use the `.outer` method of the different universal numpy functions (i.e. `numpy.subtract` to subtract values) to get easily get the results without looping over the arrays.

Comment: thanks, will use this method in the future.